# Делаю fetch запрос. При отрисовке в DOM перед элементами стоит "undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

```
fetch('https://demo5957191.mockable.io/friendStory', {method: 'GET'})
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(arr => {
    console.log(arr);
    let content;
    let allContent;
    Array.from(arr).forEach(item => {
      content += `
      <div data-number="${countfetch}" onclick="readStory(this)" class="story-card-wrap">
      <div class="story-card-wrap-head all-center">
        <p class="story-card-wrap-username">
          ${item.username}
        </p>
        <p class="story-card-wrap-title">
          ${item.storyTitle}
        </p>
        <p class="story-card-wrap-story-demo">
          ${item.storyContent}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="story-card-wrap-body all-center">
      <button class="story-card-wrap-read-story" onclick="storyOpen()">
              Читать
            </button>
        <div class="like-fav-wrap all-center">
          <button class="around-button like">

          </button>
          <button class="around-button fav">

          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      `;

      allContent += `
      <div data-number="${countfetch}" onclick="readStoryAllStory(this)" class="all-story-card">
      <div class="all-story-card-head all-center">
        <p>${item.username}</p>
      </div>



      <div class="all-story-card-body all-center">
        <div class="all-story-card-title all-center">
          <p>${item.storyTitle}</p>
          <div class="like-fav-wrap all-center all-story-like-fav-wrap">
          <button class="story-card-wrap-read-story" onclick="storyOpen()">
              Читать
            </button>
            <button class="around-button like">

            </button>
            <button class="around-button fav">

            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="all-story-card-desc">
      ${item.storyContent}
      </div>
    </div>
      `;
      countfetch++;
      undeFinedSearch();
    })
    wrap.innerHTML = content;
    allStoryWrap.innerHTML = allContent;
  })
```

Мой вопрос от том как убрать 'undefined' перед элементами которые должны отрисоваться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> let content;
> ```

```
let content = "";
```

> ```
> ${item.username}
> ```

Ну и кто это экранировать будет?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает